# Dual boot issue "Reboot and select proper device"

Tags: dual-boot

took a look around could not locate similar issue.

I amtrying to dual boot Ubuntu (latest) with Windows 7.

I followed these instructions.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

They are tonally out of date (which is a little frustrating). Also step 6 and 8 in the manual partitioning section seem to be duplicated.

I created 20 gig of space and set a swap file of 16 gb. There is no mention in the instructions on setting a root, or / location. Nore anything about using primary or logical drives. Some screens would help (I know these are probably written by volunteers, I just spent a lot of time researching to avoid this situation)

I did create this at the start of my disc, which is probably stupid, but there was no mention of this in the guide.

I used a USB (via pen drive) as the source. Everything loaded fine however now when I restart I get the message

"Reboot and select proper boot device, or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key".

If I put the usb in it asks me if I want to try or install Ubuntu. However, if I hit esc, I get to grub. Running Ls will show me a bunch of partitions. Can you help me get something working?

Comment: Boot from usb media and choose 'try ubuntu', when ubuntu starts. Open 'gparted' application from unity dash, post a screen shot of gparted in your question

Comment: Step 6 is shrinking an existing partition to make room, step 8 is creating a new partition in the newly freed up space. They are not duplicates.

Comment: If you created 20G space and used 16G of it for swap, that only leaves 4G for root...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Installing Ubuntu Disable Secure Boot in BIOS setting and Disable Fast Shutdown in Windows.

Follow these steps :

**Step 1:**
Click Install

[image]

**Step 2:**
Check both boxes

[image]

**Step 3:**
Choose something else and click next

[image]

**Step 4:**
Choose /dev/sda in "Device for boot loader installation" and Select partition of type ext 4 for Ubuntu installation.

[image]

**Step 5:**
Change Mount Point To /

[image]

**Step 6:**
Press "Install Now" to continue. Rest process is easy.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21777/discussion-on-answer-by-ubuntu99-dual-boot-issue-reboot-and-select-proper-devic).